# simple c++ nested for loop program to print a square with stars error

Tags: c++, for-loop

I'm trying to print a square using nested for loop but it always appears like the shape below and I don't know where the error is in my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size=0;
    cout << " enter hte size of the square :: " << endl;
    cin >> size;

    for(int i = 0 ; i != size; i++)
    {



        for(int j=0; j != size; j++)
        {
            if ( i == 0 || i == size-1 || j == 0 || i == size-1) cout << "* ";
            else cout << "   ";
        }

        cout << endl;

 }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
the output:

* * * * * *
*
*
*
*
* * * * * *
```

---

the ouput required:

```
* * * * * *
*         *
*         *
*         *
*         *
* * * * * *
```

---

Comment: What output did you expect instead?

Comment: i edited the post to be more clear

Comment: Time to run through your algorithm with a pencil and some paper. Pay special attention to where you write `i` and where you write `j`. In short, _read more carefully_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size=0;
    cout << " enter hte size of the square :: " << endl;
    cin >> size;

    for(int i = 0 ; i != size; i++)
    {



        for(int j=0; j != size; j++)
        {
            if ( i == 0 || i == size-1 || j == 0 || j == size-1) cout << "* ";
            else cout << "   ";
        }

        cout << endl;

 }
    return 0;
}
```

Your if statement was wrong!

Comment: @Smit Next time type MC25 and post a comment.

Comment: What is MC25? ...